# Android MainActivity thread in a for loop

Tags: java, android, multithreading, handler

I just started android dev literally 1 day ago. In the code below, i simply want the For loop to sleep for 5 seconds after every iteration. However, it only runs and prints once.
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.
Log cat: 07-31 17:49:58.656: I/System.out(511):

07-31 17:49:58.665: I/System.out(511): START

07-31 17:49:58.676: I/System.out(511): NAMECHECK: NOTAVALIBLE

07-31 17:49:58.676: I/System.out(511): SUGGESTIONS:

07-31 17:49:58.676: I/System.out(511): END

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    int count;

    try {
        String contents = "";
        u = new URL("http://rscript.org/lookup.php?type=namecheck&name=itachi");
        final HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

        for (count = 0; count < 5; count++) {
            while ((contents = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(contents);
                if (contents.contains(" AVALIBLE")) {
                    tv.setText("Available, sent mail " + count);
                    break;
                }
                tv.setText("Not Available " + count);
            }

            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                  try {
                    u = new URL("http://rscript.org/lookup.php?type=namecheck&name=itachi");
                    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }   
              }
            }, 5000);


        }


        setContentView(tv);
        con.disconnect();
        br.close();
    }
    catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Comment: You're scheduling five of them to happen in five seconds, so they all fire at once. Create a `final int countCopy = count;` right before your handler and change your `5000` to `5000*countCopy`.

Comment: Consider using a CountdownTimer.

Comment: You are trying to read from the BufferedReader immediately, but it will only be created after the time delay.  Move the read operation into the Runnable as well, and then use runOnUiThread to commit the result to the UI.

Comment: Also, no need to create five handlers. Create a single handler outside the loop.